# How can i display the maximum/minimum of count() column records in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle11g

Oracle Query

```
select
  courses.name,
  count(gardener)
from
  attendances
  join courses using (course)
group by
  courses.name
order by
  count(gardener) asc
```

Output

```
╔═══════════╦═════════════════╗
║   NAME    ║ COUNT(GARDENER) ║
╠═══════════╬═════════════════╣
║ Harvesting║               3 ║
║ Planting  ║               3 ║
║ Gardening ║               4 ║
╚═══════════╩═════════════════╝
```

How can i just display the minimum/maximum and even average count. Eg. for minimum

```
// I just want to display the courses with minimum count
╔═══════════╦═════════════════╗
║   NAME    ║ COUNT(GARDENER) ║
╠═══════════╬═════════════════╣
║ Harvesting║               3 ║
║ Planting  ║               3 ║
╚═══════════╩═════════════════╝
```

i tried

```
select
 max(cnt), -- min(cnt) and avg(cnt) doesnt seem to work
 name
from
(
  select
    courses.name,
    count(gardener) as cnt
  from
    attendances
    join courses using (course)
  group by
    courses.name
  order by
    count(gardener) asc
)
group by
  name
```

I get invalid identifier "cnt". I tried using max(cnt) it also gives me the same identifier error, can anyone correct my syntax and suggest what I'm doing wrong please or maybe suggest a different way to do it?

EDIT: i have removed the speech marks but still all of the records are being displayed, not just the maximum value count() records as i need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the courses with the minimum count, I would recommend analytic functions:

```
select name, cnt
from (select c.name, count(gardener) as cnt,
             dense_rank() over (order by count(gardener)) as seqnum
      from attendances a join
           courses c
           using (course)
      group by c.name
     ) ca
where seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

remove double quotes and then try again

Comment: Thank you, i removed speech marks and now the identifier error is gone. I have added "select max(cnt), name" + "group by name", it is still displaying all of the other records, where i just need the highest count value record to be displayed.